# Loading static JSON from local FS or remote rails server

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, json

I've looked at several questions in SO and been lead in a couple of directions have not bore fruit.

Here is my JQuery/HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        alert ("hi");

        $.getJSON("/Users/rabdelaz/Desktop/ACTFast/PM-MD.json",function(result){ //This is Version 1
        //$.getJSON("http://172.28.101.197:3000/tests.json",function(result){    //This is Version 2
            alert ("file is good");
        });
});</script>
</body>
</html>
```

First, I tried to `open -a "Google Chrome" --args --allow-file-access-from-files` (i'm on OS x) before opening my file. I used `Version 1`as shown in my code above for this part. Which gave me this:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///Users/rabdelaz/Desktop/ACTFast/PM-MD.json. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.
```

This made me think I should try to host the file on a rails server I have running.

So I tried to serve the static JSON from my rails server located on another machine. For this I used `Version 2` above. That gave me this:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://172.28.101.197:3000/tests.json. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Just for completeness, here is the controller that serves my JSON:

```
@@data = File.read("/home/rabdelaz/PM-MD.json")
# GET /tests
# GET /tests.json
def index
  render :text => @@data.to_s, :callback => params['callback']
end
```

I'm happy to ditch the rails server here but I thought it would help. I could use some help deciding on a direction to go in.

Comment: [getJSON](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) Requests have the same origin policy

Comment: How do I get around this policy? Should I use a different method/function?

Comment: I'm painfully aware of this policy by now....

Comment: In the docs it says you can use .jsonp. Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506208/jquery-ajax-cross-domain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try adding this to your rails method

```
 headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
 headers['Access-Control-Request-Method'] = '*'
```